# Is it appropriate to ask for a clarification about a sexually oriented joke?

Tags: discussion, appropriate-questions

There was a joke in a recent episode of SouthPark (BlockBuster) that makes a direct reference to an adult movie. English is not my mother language, so I'm not sure if I've understood the joke completely. May I ask for a clarification here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jokes which rely on the English language are at least implicitly [on topic in the FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). The fact that it makes a direct reference to an adult movie doesn't change that.

Such a reference *may* make the question **too localised**, though.

> ***Too localized:*** This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

The community can only make a judgement on that when the question is known.

The joke or its explanation may be [Not Safe For Work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_safe_for_work) which might cause some difficulties, although a reasonable academic discussion of the words used has certainly appeared before. It's possible to find [some examples](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=cunt) which are almost certainly NSFW: if your browser shows you the end of that link you can use your judgement about whether to follow it.

Comment: OK. I'll look for the answer with some fans of the show.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think I was saying *don't ask here*; but if you can find an answer elsewhere, all well and good.

Comment: I think that it will be too localized.

Comment: Indeed, request for explanation of most jokes (sexual or not) will be too localized.